# Prevent OpsWorks from overwriting the CodeIgniter's "system" directory with a symlink

Tags: amazon-web-services, codeigniter, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I have multiple CodeIgniter applications that I want to deploy with Amazon OpsWorks with a very standard "PHP App Server" layer and a custom recipe to adjust permissions. The problem is that the deploy script seems to automatically remove any `current/public/system` directory and replace it by a symlink to `shared/system`.

This is pretty annoying because all the CodeIgniter's files used to be within the `current/public/system` directory.

Anyone know how to prevent OpsWorks from creating this symlink ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible UNLESS you create your own modified version of the AWS Cookbook that does this. The specific reason for this is the recipes at : [here](https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks/blob/release-chef-11.10/deploy/definitions/opsworks_deploy_dir.rb)

A Possible Work around this :

```
## deploy/before_migrate.rb (in your app repo )

deploy_to = deploy_resource.deploy_to

dirs_to_protect = [ "public" ]
dirs_to_protect.each {|dir| 
    bash "save #{dir}" do
      code <<-EOL
        cp -a #{release_path}/#{dir}/* #{deploy_to}/shared/#{dir} 
      EOL
    end
}
```

This will save the dirs you need to protect in the shared folder where the symlink is sent to. You can easily change the destination, or just write another hook after the symlink to remove the symlinked directories. etc. Keep in mind that if it's not a default folder, you will need to create it yourself inside the loop.

More about Hooks : [Chef Deployment Hooks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingcookbook-extend-hooks.html)

Comment: What you tell here is that I can't install CodeIgniter or ExpressionEngine with the opsworks cookbook for php. CodeIgniter is still a very popular framework. This is a major bug in the cookbook. May you help me to push this issue ? https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks/issues/153

Comment: There are hooks available that will let you mitigate this. I have listed them now.  Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, I'll test that later but it looks like a good idea. :)